# How to use a deprecated import in java?

Tags: java, import, deprecated

I have a `.jar` library that uses a deprecated import `"sun.misc.ref"` but now it should be `"java.lang.ref.SoftReference"` how can I point to that?

Below, I'm posting the error I get. I'm using acrobat reader api 1.1, and yes, I would like to open the `.pdf` file inside my application and not outside.

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Ref
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.adobe.pe.notify.VValuePurgeable.<init>(VValuePurgeable.java:92)
    at com.adobe.acrobat.gui.VOrnamentList.<init>(VOrnamentList.java:16)
    at com.adobe.acrobat.gui.PageView$VGalleyOrnaments.<init>(PageView.java:1083)
    at com.adobe.acrobat.gui.PageView.<init>(PageView.java:1081)
    at com.adobe.acrobat.gui.AcroViewContext.commonInit(AcroViewContext.java:166)
    at com.adobe.acrobat.gui.AcroViewContext.<init>(AcroViewContext.java:99)
    at com.adobe.acrobat.Viewer.createViewer(Viewer.java:243)
    at com.adobe.acrobat.Viewer.<init>(Viewer.java:211)
    at screens.PdfReader_AcrobatReader.<init>(PdfReader_AcrobatReader.java:38)
    at screens.Main.pdf(Main.java:344)
    at screens.Library_Book.tblMouseLeftBtn(Library_Book.java:101)
    at screens.Library_Book.access$000(Library_Book.java:22)
    at screens.Library_Book$2.mousePressed(Library_Book.java:56)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:288)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6629)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Ref
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Either get a newer version or you need to update the jar yourself. But check the license first, if you're allowed to modify its code.

Comment: Are you using this 13 year-old library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.adobe.acrobat/acrobat/1.1)?

Comment: Which Java version are you using? You may want to tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm using jdk 11 - current version. Yes, the same 13 yo library. Believe or not, it has some functions that hasn't been implemented in others of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to just point to the new ref; the deprecation warning means a little more than just 'what we used to call sun.misc.ref is now called java.lang.ref.SoftReference'; the entire API has changed.

You have to fix this in the source code and recompile. I presume that the source code isn't available? That'd mean you can't address this at all.

If you must run this code and there is no alternative, find an (outdated and therefore unsupported) old version of the JVM and run it on that. Don't use this VM to run random java stuff (i.e. don't make it the default VM if you doubleclick a jar or whatnot), don't access arbitrary internet resources with it (i.e. don't use this PDF viewer to view URLs), and load only PDFs from trustworthy entities. After all, if there are security issues with the library or the VM, they won't be acknowledged or fixed.

For what it's worth, JDK8 should still have sun.misc.ref; try running on that. There are even JDK8 variants that are still supported, such as [coretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/). I'd start there, and only if you can't run this on JDK8, try even older VMs.

Answer (score 1):

A search of the Java 11 source tree tells me that the class `sun.misc.Ref` no longer exists in Java 11.  It is not (just) deprecated.  It has been entirely removed.  And there is no package named `sun.misc.ref` either.

Bottom line is that Acrobat API won't work on Java 11.  Your choices are limited:

- Use an older version of Java prior to the removal ... until that version goes EOL.  Java 8 or earlier.
- Try and find a newer version of that API that is Java 11 compatible.
- Try and find the source for the API and port it.
- Find an alternative API.
- Drop this functionality from your product.

<sup>(There are a couple of other ideas that are extremely painful and / or risky ... which I won't mention.)</sup>